# How do I pass in multiple values in the nullfieldlist using the netsuite connector within Mulesoft dataweave

Tags: netsuite, dataweave, mulesoft

within my transform process I need to null out 2 fields and I am trying to do this in the mulesoft 4 dataweave, but it is only accounting for the second item and not both.

```
       %dw 2.0
       output application/java
       import * from dw::core::Strings
       ---
      {
       customFieldList: {
                   customField: [
                                 {ScriptId: "custentity_wip_commission_payment",
                                    value: {  internalId: payload.commisionpayment as String default ""} as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.ListOrRecordRef"}
                                    } as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.SelectCustomFieldRef"},

                                {ScriptId: "custentity_wip_accounting_status",
                                    value: {  internalId: payload.accountingstatus as String default ""} as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.ListOrRecordRef"}
                                    } as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.SelectCustomFieldRef"},

                                {ScriptId: "custentity_wip_retain",
                                    value: {  internalId: payload.retain as String default ""} as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.ListOrRecordRef"}
                                    } as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.SelectCustomFieldRef"},

                                {ScriptId: "custentity_wip_schedule",
                                    value: {  internalId: payload.wipschedule as String default ""} as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.ListOrRecordRef"}
                                    } as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.SelectCustomFieldRef"},

                                {scriptId: "custentity_wip_salesrep",
                                    value:   payload.salesrep as String default ""} as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.StringCustomFieldRef"}, 

                                {ScriptId: "custentity_wip_agentcountry",
                                    value: {  internalId: payload.agentcountry as String default ""} as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.ListOrRecordRef"}
                                    } as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.SelectCustomFieldRef"}

                                ]
                   } as Object {class: "org.mule.module.netsuite.extension.api.CustomFieldList"},


       nullFieldList: {"name": "custentity_wip_accounting_status",
                       "name": "custentity_wip_commission_payment"
                  },
```

Comment: Can you share your dataweave?  Can you show what you want your output to look like?

Comment: I added more details on the origina post.  Basically i have a couple of custom fields that were created, but I want to be able to reset them to null, if they are not reset to null, they wind up retaining the original value

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by creating the entry in a list form.

```
  nullFieldList: {"name": ["custentity_wip_accounting_status","custentity_wip_commission_payment"]
                  },
```